# How to fetch json data by angular 4

Tags: angular, angular5, angular2-forms

I am trying to get matched data from json file but not working. can you findout where i did mistake?

```
this.http.get('test.json')
.subscribe((res: Response) => { 
this.result = res.json(); 
this.displayItems = this.result;
}, error => {
console.log(error);
this.errorFromSubscribe = error;
});
```

Comment: Don't you need to escape the url because of whitespace in path: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: Can you edit my stackblitz?

Comment: Stackblitz won't work, it won't load JSON because of CORS. try to apply URLEncode in ur code

Comment: @Suresh Kumar Ariya:   Can you edit my stackblitz ..i can copy and past in my localhost folder..brcause i am trying this work in my locahost folder

Comment: I think that stackblitz is the problem here because you can't even access to https://http-get-json-yw4pj2.stackblitz.io/jsondata/details.json as a json file.
Try your code in a local setup

Comment: I can't edit your stackblitz

Comment: @davidonet:  Can you edit my code to match my local setup?

Comment: you can find the snipet in my answer

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comment remove all the white-spaces from the requested URL and you your request should pass through. I have seen some json format error though which can be related with reposne you are getting from the API. But can verify that request passed with status 200.

```
onClick() {
      this.http.get('./jsondata/details.json?nm=Cnut&cty=UnitedKingdom&hse=HouseofDenmark&yrs=yrs')
      .subscribe((res: Response) => { 
        console.log(res);
        this.displayItems = this.result;
      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
        this.errorFromSubscribe = error;
      });

  }
}
```

Comment: @SEERANSV: just copy paste the onclick function posted above in your code sample  and you should see the response in the console.

Comment: Getting this error:ERROR Error: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: That looks like the response from the API is not in proper JSON format. If you replace the res.json() with just res and console.log(res) as i did in my function posted above, you will see the status 200. I believe your major concern was to make the proper request.

Comment: StackBlitz does not support local http requests indeed you cannot see the response https://http-get-json-yw4pj2.stackblitz.io/jsondata/details.json You should try the answers in your local environment

Answer (score 0):

Use this code on your localhost, check that `http://localhost/jsondata/details.json` is reachable

```
 this.http.get('./jsondata/details.json?'+encodeURIComponent('nm=Cnut&cty=United Kingdom&hse=House of Denmark&yrs=yrs'))
          .subscribe((res: Response) => { 
            this.result = res.json(); 
            this.displayItems = this.result;
          }, error => {
            console.log(error);
            this.errorFromSubscribe = error;
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the problem that the JSON file is not reachable when you tested it. Please try to deploy your JSON into an accessible URL or properly setup your local dev environment.

Alternatively if you just want the data, and your JSON file is not insanely big, you can just import it into your Angular code, rather than make HTTP call to get it.

`import * as data from './jsondata/details.json'`